# scale_x_date remove extra month on axis (ggplot2 2.2.0.9)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using a line chart with a time scale and the last point is December 30th. However, with scale_x_date, January shows up on the scale even though there is data point for that month.

the scale should really stop at the last month but I believe this is because of the day. Is there a way to have the scale stick to the actual months in the data?

I am using this to format the scale:

```
#with lubridate
data$month <- ymd(data$month)

#in the plot
scale_x_date(date_breaks = "1 month", date_labels ="%b %y")
```

Reproducible example:

```
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)

cities <- c("city1")
month <- c("2016-08-01", "2016-09-30", "2016-10-30", "2016-11-30", "2016-12-30")
num <- c(23287, 23889, 25026, 26116, 29758)

data <- data.frame(cities, month, num)
data$month <- ymd(data$month)

gg <- ggplot(data, aes(month, num, group = 1)
gg <- gg + geom_line(position = "identity", color="#6baed6")
gg <- gg + scale_y_continuous(expand = (c(0.1,0)))
gg <- gg + scale_x_date(expand = c(0, 0), date_labels ="%b %y")
gg <- gg + labs(x = NULL, y = NULL)
gg <- gg + theme(strip.background=element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme_bw()
gg <- gg + theme(panel.border = element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(axis.ticks=element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=12))
gg <- gg + theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size=12))
gg
```

In, this example, without expand(), January is added even though there is no data point in January.

There is one data point per month and my goal is to display the data by month. I could convert to factor but this is not ideal. I understand the data has a day but surely there must be a way to do this.

Comment: if you add the argument `expand = c(0, 0)`, does it work?

Comment: It does but now the points are skipping one month and offset. Your solution works, but something else is going on. One month doesn't have a point even though its in the data set.

Comment: You could try setting expand to be very small but > 0. Proving some data (use `dput`) would help to make the problem reproducible.

Comment: Let me add a reproducible example.

Comment: I'm unsure what your desired breaks on the x axis are. Please clarify. It will look awkward if you have 2016-12-30 but don't show a January date on the axis.

Comment: Breaks are: Sep 16 Oct 16 Nov 16 Dec 16. I have added an example. I am unsure why it would be awkward. There is one data point per month, my goal is to display the data by month. I could convert to factor, but its not ideal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't consider this a good plot, but here you are. You probably want to set the breaks to the 15th day of each month:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data, aes(month, num, group = 1)) + 
  geom_line(position = "identity", color="#6baed6") + 
  #scale_y_continuous(expand = (c(0.1,0)), labels = comma) +
  scale_x_date(breaks = seq(as.Date("2016-07-15"), 
                            as.Date("2016-12-15"), by = "1 month"), date_labels ="%b %y") + 
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) + 
  theme_bw() +
  theme(strip.background=element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks=element_blank(),
        axis.text=element_text(size=12))
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: That works. Thanks! I am curious, what would be a better plot?

Comment: One where you'd have axis ticks and show the complete dates on the axis. Alternatively a plot with axis ticks on the first day of the month and axis labels between the ticks.

Comment: Fair comments. I am not including the complete dates as this is an ongoing time series and the day will become irrelevant because the data is collected on the same day onward and it would make the chart harder to read. Showing just the month is enough to see what is going on, in my opinion.